# How do you make Hull Hotcakes?

Tags: baking, pancakes, breakfast

I am fast going barmy trying to find someone who remembers the Hull Hotcake recipe. This hot cake was very very popular over generations through to the 1960's then seems to have disappeared.

It was a fairly flat, doughy bread with a thin, crusty surface. Beautiful with crispy bacon or sausage inside.

Anybody out there remember the recipe? This is unique to the Hull (UK) area. Surely I am not the last person left standing who remembers the Hull Hotcake!

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice, Dr. Edwards! I've proposed some edits to your post just to help with formatting and clarity. Recipe requests are typically considered off topic here as we've found they aren't usually a good fit for our Q&A format. The specificity of your question and the fact that you can't easily answer it by googling might put it into a gray area though. Either way, I hope you find your hotcakes!

Comment: Unfortunately recipe requests are off-topic here.

Comment: Elendil is correct. Even with the change in title, this is still a recipe request, and we don't take those.

Comment: This should never have been closed -- restaurant mimicry questions are explicitly allowed.  And do we have proof that 'hull hotcakes' are pannenkoeken?  Pannenkoeken are similar enough to British pancakes that I suspect Raymond would have described the subtle differences, and not have said 'fairly flat'.

Comment: @Joe, I found the references to Pannenkoeken with the types of added ingredients the OP described in menus from restaurants in the Hull area. From what I could find out, they were very popular in that area and match his description very well. I also noted in my edit that they use a pretty standard batter, so I suspected that the cooking method is what made them a little different than other similar pancakes. I agree that this should not have been closed.

Comment: @Cindy Since these were around only until the 1960's I suspect he is talking about [havercakes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staffordshire_oatcake#Lancashire_and_Yorkshire_oatcakes).

Comment: @Cindy : I'm seeing mentioned of pannekoeken in Hull, but the place  [opened in 2014](http://www.hullbid.co.uk/articles/240) and suggested the concept is novel.  There's also a place in Hull that [sells American pancakes](http://www.pancakehouse.info/menu/), including "[b]uttermilk pancakes filled with real bits of bacon".  The 'many other ingredients that can be added' and 'can be made sweet or savory' doesn't exclude pannekoeken, but also sound like the oatcakes in Chris' link.  The reference to a standard batter threw me, because I had assumed that was in the original question.

Comment: @Joe, based on your comment I did a rollback on the question. That will open the question to more answers, rather than just those about Pannenkoeken, assuming it is reopened. I still think, based on the OP's description and the information I found, that Pannenkoeken is on target. However, if reopened, I can put that information along with links to the sources in an answer.